# w3schools tab - All tab

Tags: javascript, html

I am just starting with javascript and kind of stuck in w3schools tabs.
I want to create a tab - "Everything" which shows the content of all the tabs. I am unable to figure out how to do it without duplicating the content.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">

   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
 </div>

<!-- Tab content -->
 <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>London</h3>
   <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>Paris</h3>
   <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
 </div>

 <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>Tokyo</h3>
   <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is a "w3schools tabs" ??

Comment: as an early note: avoid w3schools, it uses bad practices. Reference w3.org and MDN instead

Comment: @treyBake has given here probably the best career advice anyone could tell you, run away, really really far away from w3schools. My teacher already said that back in the days in which I was a student, and ever since I never got any1 that liked it. So trust nothing else than the official docs, this means MDN and w3.org

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish? You can just create a showAll function which will set back the initial values.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function showAll(){
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "initial";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">

   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="showAll()">Show all</button>
 </div>

<!-- Tab content -->
 <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>London</h3>
   <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>Paris</h3>
   <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
 </div>

 <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
   <h3>Tokyo</h3>
   <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Make an array and iterate to all and make it as block when it is everything.

```
      <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Everything')">Everything</button>
      </div>

      <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>London</h3>
        <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
      </div>

      <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Tokyo</h3>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
      </div>



      <script>
          function openCity(evt, cityName) {

        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
        }
        if(cityName === 'Everything'){
            const arr = ['London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo'];
          for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
          }
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: code-only answers aren't answers IMO - needs to actually explain the problem/solution :)